# Unit tests: creating and deleting entry with SQL Query

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm pretty new to this, and I'm trying to make a test where I can create and delete an object in a mock Database but I have no idea where to start now or how to create that Mock database and read/write to it.

```
    [Fact]
    public void CreateCommentaar()
    {
        //arrange
        Commentaar commentaar = new Commentaar
        {
            CommentaarId = 0,
            StadId = 0,
            UserId = "testId",
            CommentaarText = "text",
            Tijdstip = DateTime.Now
        };

        string queryString = "INSERT INTO Commentaar(UserId, StadId, CommentaarText, Tijdstip) VALUES("
            + commentaar.CommentaarId + " ,"
            + commentaar.UserId + " ,"
            + commentaar.StadId + " ,"
            + commentaar.CommentaarText + " ,"
            + commentaar.Tijdstip + " ,";

        //act
        //Run Mock sql query

        //assert
        //1 commentaar object should exist in mock DB now

    }

    [Fact]
    public void DeleteCommentaar()
    {
        //arrange
        Commentaar commentaar = new Commentaar
        {
            CommentaarId = 0,
            StadId = 0,
            UserId = "testId",
            CommentaarText = "text",
            Tijdstip = DateTime.Now
        };

        string queryString = "INSERT INTO Commentaar(UserId, StadId, CommentaarText, Tijdstip) VALUES("
            + commentaar.CommentaarId + " ,"
            + commentaar.UserId + " ,"
            + commentaar.StadId + " ,"
            + commentaar.CommentaarText + " ,"
            + commentaar.Tijdstip + " ,";

        //act
        //Run Mock sql query

        //assert
        //1 commentaar object should be deleted
    }
```

I'm not really sure how to continue from here though.

Comment: Can you share the code which you are trying to unit test? If you are directly interacting with database then it is not unit testing but it is Integration testing.

Comment: Rather than testing whether your DBMS responds correctly to an insert or delete command, you no doubt have a save or delete method on your dac. Your unit testing would normally be determining whether the appropriate command and parameters get passed from your dac in response to a given object.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't have that code, that's the thing I needed help with, because I don't know or can't find how to continue from here. All I have is the model and that bit of pseudocode

Comment: If you mock out the database and write the SQL in your test you surely aren't covering any of your code with the test? How does your code talk to the database? If that's hard coded to a specific db you won't be able to mock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't anything to test here. Testing if something would be inserted in the mock database would be testing your mock logic.

Testing if your sql queries are correct is best done using integration tests and a test database.

Comment: You're pretty much right. For now I've just tested wether calling the service also correctly calls the repository that the SQL query is in, and I don't think I can do much more than that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just start a

```
string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Commentaar where id = 0"
```

If that query return 0 it means that your Commentaar has been deleted.

> **ONE PROBLEM** It will only works if your first UT worked and inserted a line with 0 as ID.